# interpolate linear array to non linear array using python numpy or scipy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

i have to arrays:

a linear one;

```
x = array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. , 1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4])
```

And a corresponding result which is a non-linear one;

```
y = array([ 13.07,  13.7 ,  14.35,  14.92,  15.5 ,  16.05,  16.56,  17.12,
        17.62,  18.08,  18.55,  19.02,  19.45,  19.88,  20.25])
```

*Now*: I want to convert y to a linearly spaced array and find the corresponding interpolated values of `x`.

i.e. find x when

```
y = array([ 13. ,  13.5,  14. ,  14.5,  15. ,  15.5,  16. ,  16.5,  17. , 17.5,  18. ,  18.5,  19. ,  19.5,  20. ])
```

Thanks in advance.

I use the following method using the interp function in numpy:

```
ynew = np.linspace(np.min(y), np.max(y), len(y))
xnew = np.interp(ynew, y, x)
```

i.e. exchanging x and y in the np.interp function.

Is this always correct ? or will it break down for some condition.

Comment: How do you want to get from y1 to y2?  What's the logic there?

Comment: @jedwards it is simply some measured data. no logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, this case calls for a simple invocation of `numpy.interp`.  You want to predict `x` from `y` which is the reverse of how people usually do their variable definitions, but other than that wrinkle, all you need is:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. , 1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4])
y = np.array([ 13.07,  13.7 ,  14.35,  14.92,  15.5 ,  16.05,  16.56,  17.12,
        17.62,  18.08,  18.55,  19.02,  19.45,  19.88,  20.25])
ynew = np.array([ 13. ,  13.5,  14. ,  14.5,  15. ,  15.5,  16. ,  16.5,  17. , 17.5,  18. ,  18.5,  19. ,  19.5,  20. ])
xnew = np.interp(ynew, y, x)
print xnew
```

Which gives as ouput:

```
[ 0.          0.06825397  0.14615385  0.22631579  0.3137931   0.4
  0.49090909  0.58823529  0.67857143  0.776       0.8826087   0.9893617
  1.09574468  1.21162791  1.33243243]
```

Comment: i just found that answer myself. so i have modified my question to find wheather this method is valid for all cases.

Comment: Sorry I missed your edit superbuch -- it looks like it came in after my answer?  Either way, I hope the answer was still useful to you.  I think the `np.interp` function is generally useful, but without knowing exactly what you mean by "all" cases, I would hesitate to use that word.

Comment: thanks for answer. By all cases i mean when either x or y or both are negative or when one or the other or both are decreasing or one is increasing and the other is decreasing.

Comment: You could try a few quick variations: `np.interp(ynew, y[::-1], x[::-1])`,  `np.interp(ynew, -y[::-1], -x[::-1])`,  `np.interp(-ynew[::-1], -y[::-1], -x[::-1])`, etc., and see which ones work and which ones run into problems.  At least a few of those will give results that are not useful.  It took a moment or two but eventually for each one I realized what the problem was.